# In WinRT, how do I load an image and then wait only as long as is needed for it to load before writing to it?

Tags: windows-runtime, async-await, writeablebitmap, filepicker, writeablebitmapex

I'm using WriteableBitmapEx in a WinRT project.  I load an image into a WriteableBitmap from the users Picture library.  However, I cannot then immediately write to that image, if I do, it will be overwritten with the image itself (it seems like it's Async loading the image and then it's overwritting my drawing on top of it).  I don't know how to stop it from doing that (I tried using Await on the SetSource but that's not an Async method).

I've used an "Await Task.Delay(1000)" and that works, but it seems hacky because 1000ms may or may not be enough time.. I would like it to wait until the bitmap is loaded before proceeding.

Can anyone seem off the top what I'm doing wrong or suggest how I can ensure the WriteableBitmap is loaded from the pictures library before doing any processing?  Here's the example code snippet I created:

```
Dim file = Await picker.PickSingleFileAsync

If file Is Nothing Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim wbm As New WriteableBitmap(1, 1)
wbm.SetSource(Await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))

' If I don't have this, the DrawLine will not show up, if I do, it will.
Await Task.Delay(1000)

wbm.DrawLine(1, 1, 255, 255, Colors.Green)
wbm.Invalidate()

ImageMain.Source = wbm
```

Comment: You're using this project?  http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Comment: I think it's my WinRT version of it - http://bit.ly/WriteableBitmapExWinRT

Comment: I'm using Filip's WinRT port of it and I have been able to use it to manipulate the graphics.  Btw, thanks for that Filip. :)  Once I finish learning all of this I'm going to post source code.

Comment: WinRT is now officially supported by WriteableBitmapEx. ;) It's still in a branch, but I plan to release it next week. For now just check out the code from here: https://writeablebitmapex.svn.codeplex.com/svn/branches/WBX_1.0_BitmapContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenAsync returning just means the stream is available, not that the data is actually read from it.  It seems like you would therefore want to both open + read first and then you would be fine.

Since Filip pointed out that ReadAsync would require you to create and pass in a buffer first, I've updated the below snippet to use [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208119.aspx) to actually load the stream into the byte array after doing OpenReadAsync to get the IRandomAccessStream.

```
var randomAccessStream = await file.OpenReadAsync();

var dataReader = new DataReader(randomAccessStream);
await dataReader.LoadAsync(randomAccessStream.Size);

byte[] imageBytes;
dataReader.ReadBytes(out imageBytes);

wbm.SetSource(new MemoryStream(imageBytes));
```

Comment: I'm going to give this a try also, thank you for the feedback James.

Comment: Interesting, but why would it be a difference if you read from the file stream and then provide the contents as a MemoryStream? It's the WriteableBitmap that needs to read the stream - it does not seem like it would care what type of stream it gets. The benefit of your approach is that if you also close the file stream - you can delete the file before WB displayes its contents.

Comment: @FilipSkakun - I really don't want to provide a stream at all - I originally posted the the snippet doing SetSource(imageBytes) and then happened to notice it has no such overload.  There's probably a way of creating a WritableBitmap from a byte array and I just couldn't find it (maybe use Image.Create?  Not sure), but indeed, you really wouldn't want to use streams at all.  Using the MemoryStream is really relying on an implementation detail that the SetSource will be fast enough and/or synchronous with the MemoryStream to be done before the later DrawLine.

Comment: Wait, how do you call ReadAsync with no parameters?

Comment: Sorry, that's what I get for just typing it in to SO - looks like you would indeed have to allocate a buffer for the file contents first.  :)

Comment: @FilipSkakun - I changed it to use DataReader to pull in the file contents instead.  Hopefully that'll work fine.  I need to get a Win8 VM going so I can actually test this stuff soon. :)

Comment: I have a possibly related problem that I had stumbled upon and then considered your answer here to fix... I was doing fileStream = StorageFile.OpenReadAsync() and then MediaElement.SetSource(fileStream, fileStream.ContentType) on a wav file and my file would only play halfway through and then stop, but when I did clone = fileStream.CloneStream() and then MediaElement.SetSource(clone, fileStream.ContentType) - the file played fine. Definitely something wonky going on with file streams here. Apparently WriteableBitmap handles things fine eventually, but MediaElement does not...

Answer (score 8):

This method loads an image from the app's content, decodes it and passes back an ready-to-use WriteableBitmap. 
Taken from the [WriteableBitmapEx library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/):

```
/// <summary>
/// Loads an image from the applications content and fills this WriteableBitmap with it.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="bmp">The WriteableBitmap.</param>
/// <param name="uri">The URI to the content file.</param>
/// <returns>The WriteableBitmap that was passed as parameter.</returns>
public static async Task<WriteableBitmap> FromContent(this WriteableBitmap bmp, Uri uri)
{
   // Decode pixel data
   var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
   var decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read));
   var transform = new global::Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapTransform();
   var pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, decoder.BitmapAlphaMode, transform, ExifOrientationMode.RespectExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.ColorManageToSRgb);
   var pixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();

   // Copy to WriteableBitmap
   bmp = new WriteableBitmap((int)decoder.PixelWidth, (int)decoder.PixelHeight);
   using (var bmpStream = bmp.PixelBuffer.AsStream())
   {
      bmpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      bmpStream.Write(pixels, 0, (int)bmpStream.Length);
      return bmp;
   }
}
```

BTW, WinRT is now officially supported by WriteableBitmapEx. ;) 
http://kodierer.blogspot.de/2012/05/one-bitmap-to-rule-them-all.html

Comment: +1, but this workaround sucks. I really hope they get this in shape before WinRT ships.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think WB has the events that BitmapImage does to wait for it to open. I would try using BitmapDecoder/CreateAsync/GetPixelDataAsync/DetachPixelData and copy resulting byte array to the WB's pixel buffer instead of calling wb.SetSource(). Then maybe call wb.Invalidate(). Or maybe just replace the Delay call with an Invalidate one.

Comment: I'll give both of those a try.  Thanks again Filip for helping me understand/learn.  It's much appreciated.