# how to save MemoryStream to JPEG in Windows 8 c#

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, memorystream

I see solution for this problem:
[Saving as jpeg from memorystream in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10661967/saving-as-jpeg-from-memorystream-in-c-sharp)

but it does not work in winRT.
Is there a simple way to save MemoryStream  as JPEG using FileSavePicker?

I tried:

```
private async void Save_Image(MemoryStream image)
{ 
// Launch file picker
    FileSavePicker picker = new FileSavePicker();
    picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPeg", new List<string>() { ".jpg", ".jpeg" });
    StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();

    if (file == null)
        return;

    Stream x = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync();
    image.WriteTo(x)
}
```

but it is saving blank file. May be I am doing something wrong.

Tried one more approach but again blank image:

```
private async void Save_Image(MemoryStream image)
    {
        // Launch file picker
        FileSavePicker picker = new FileSavePicker();
        picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPeg", new List<string>() { ".jpg", ".jpeg" });
        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();            

        if (file == null)
            return;

        int end = (int)image.Length;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[end];                        
        await image.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, end);
        await FileIO.WriteBytesAsync(file, buffer);
    }
```

Comment: Where did you get `image` from?

Comment: oh sorry for that, missed few initial lines. here we go: 

`private async void Save_Image(MemoryStream image) {`

Comment: Why are you using a MemoryStream for image bytes? If your intent is to create a image or modify and existing image, you might be better served with the WriteableBitmap class.

Comment: Here is another SO question that may help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197170/in-winrt-how-do-i-load-an-image-and-then-wait-only-as-long-as-is-needed-for-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! It was the seeking position I was missing and also the "using". Had to set it externally to 0.
Here is the code:

```
private async void Save_Image(MemoryStream image)
    {
        // Launch file picker
        FileSavePicker picker = new FileSavePicker();
        picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPeg", new List<string>() { ".jpg", ".jpeg" });
        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();            

        if (file == null)
            return;
        using (Stream x = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            x.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            image.WriteTo(x);
        }

    }
```